# combining multiple buttons into a single button

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a code where I need to click multiple buttons in a particular order to get the result I need.

All the buttons are written in:

```
Public Sub CommandButton1, 2, 3, etc_Click()
```

is there a way to click only one button which will include let say 5 buttons in the order I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can call the Click-Sub of a button from another Sub.

```
Public Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    CommandButton2_Click
    CommandButton3_Click
    CommandButton4_Click
    CommandButton5_Click
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can click the buttons with the following functions:

```
CommandButton1_Click
```

So for example you can make a new button with the code of :

```
CommandButton1_Click
CommandButton2_Click
```

etc.

I hope this works for you if not then please comment and I will search a bit more on the topic.

Answer (score -1):

To add to Dorians answer you could also do below which would run all code under each button

```
Public Sub Click_All_Buttons()
    CommandButton1_Click
    CommandButton2_Click
    CommandButton3_Click
    CommandButton4_Click
    CommandButton5_Click
End Sub
```